# Translate WordPress words

Tags: wordpress, translate

I would like to translate some expressions from English to French.
I created a file fr_FR.po and an other fr_FR.mo with the good expressions using POEdit software.

But when I put them on the server, the words are always the same, in English ...

Morevover, I tried to change words directly in WordPress files, again, it didn't work !

So do you have an idea ?

Comment: Just download the translated version? https://fr.wordpress.org/

Comment: Hum .. I don't know how to do that ^^

Comment: It's just some words, like "Login / Register" or the 404 page